# How to connect WordPress to ActiveCampaign database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a website for a company on WordPress. Their old client/contact database was with WildApricot. They wanted to now use ActiveCampaign as a hosting service, and I've since exported all our our client/contact data to ActiveCampaign.

Now here's the problem. The ActiveCampaign database has all of our client information, including passwords, emails, and profile information.

What I am trying to do is create a new connection in WordPress to ActiveCampaign, but I am unsure of how to do this. I understand the gist of it, but cannot find any information on how to get database information for ActiveCampaign. Stuff like, DB name, host, etc. so I can use that in a new wpdb class.

Keep in mind my PHP is limited, as I haven't had much exposure to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ActiveCampaign PHP API to connect with ActiveCampaign.

https://github.com/ActiveCampaign/activecampaign-api-php

For that you will need your API KEY and API URL, that you can find in AC under "settings" > "developer".

Using the API you can retrieve the information from your contacts and store in WP in the way you want it to be.

Another option is try to use Zapier and see if they have an integration for what you need.